# How to access user settings using Exchange web service managed API?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, autodiscovery

I am trying to access user settings of a mailbox using exchange web service(using OAuth). I am able to read inbox mails but looks like to get user settings we need to create Autodiscover service. I am unable to get the user settings using above service. If any one already used the autodiscover service with OAuth authentication please guide me on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected If your code is using the client credentials flow and [an Autodiscover POX request that is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/development/pox-autodiscover-not-supported-oauth-client-credentials-grant) .

If this is not the case, then you need to show a bit of the code you are using.

If you just need to get the EWS endpoint using Autodiscover then you can use Autodiscover v2 which is unauthenticated e.g. use an HTTP Get to

```
https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.json?Email=bgates@microsoft.com&Protocol=EWS
```